# Reasons for the lack of differentiation in words related to professions

Tags: historia, sufijos

Take the following semantic groups in English:

- [Politics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/politics); [political](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/political); [politician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/politician).
- [Mathematics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mathematics); [mathematical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mathematical); [mathematician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mathematician).
- [Music](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/music); [musical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/musical); [musician](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/musician).

The pattern is clear: given the noun for a discipline, you can add the suffix **-al** to form the adjective meaning "related to such discipline", or you can add the suffix **-ian** to form the noun meaning "someone whose profession is such discipline".  Thus getting distinct words for each concept.

In Spanish, however, it seems to be more common to use the same word for several, if not all of those different meanings:

- [Política](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ta2HMYR#PHkNCBS); [política](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ta2HMYR#CayGFe6); [política](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ta2HMYR#CazyVnS).
- [Matemáticas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ObS8ajk#SIet2iW); [matemáticas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ObS8ajk#AahatC6); [matemáticas](http://Aahyb2i).
- [Música](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q9MHl5m#SDb4GEP); musical*; [música](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q9MHl5m#BBmUnIU).

<sup><sup>* Though the DLE still defines [músico, a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q9MHl5m) as «1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la música. *Instrumento músico. Composición música*.»</sup></sup>

The list goes on: [médico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ol43qKz), [técnica](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZIkyMDs)...

**Question**: has it always been like this? Did Spanish ever had a specific suffix for the above professions, equivalent to English *-ian*, and then it got lost? Why (or why not)?

Comment: I am pleased to see my own profession _estadístico_ is rule conforming in both languages but I wonder whether the termination -ca or -cas is crucial here in Spanish (and -c or -cs in English). For instance there are many professions ending _-logo_ in Spanish (and -logist in English).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

[image]

---

The reason for the lack of differentiation in Spanish is that **there was often a lack of differentiation in Latin**, e.g.

- *mathēmaticus* meaning both *mathematical* and *mathematician*
- *medicus* meaning both *medical* and *physician*

In these words, the English suffixed versions are either semi-learned latinisms (e.g. *mathematics* +‎ *-al*), or adaptions of the French (e.g. mathématicien < *mathématique* + *-ien*). So, the question might be more meaningfully posed, **why did French/English a̲d̲d̲ this differentiation in such words?**

Of course, as you note, this lack of differentiation in Spanish/3-way differentiation in English is far from universal. Exceptions run in both directions in all sorts of flavours:

**topic / person / adj**

- "...ic"

  - `En` <s>anorexia</s>, anorexic, anorexic
    `Es` <s>anorexia</s>, anoréxico, anoréxico
  - `En` electronics, electronic, [...]
    `Es` electrónico, electrónico, [...]

**adjective**

- "...al"

  - `En` diagonal, cerebral, additional
    `Es` diagonal, cerebral, adicional
- "...ic"

  - algebraic, acrobatic, biographic
    algebraico, acrobático, biográfico
- "...ian"

  - microbian, Gregorian, Euclidean
    microbiano, gregoriano, euclidiano

**person**

- "...ian"

  - citizen, Hawaiian, Italian
    ciudadano, hawaiano, italiano

**mismatches**

- provincial, parroquial, mundane
  provinciano, parroquiano, mundial (mundano)

---

**Sources**

<sup>• [https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categoría:ES:Palabras_con_el_sufijo_-ano](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:ES:Palabras_con_el_sufijo_-ano)</sup>
 <sup>• [https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categoría:ES:Palabras_con_el_sufijo_-al](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:ES:Palabras_con_el_sufijo_-al)</sup>
 <sup>• https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Spanish_words_suffixed_with_-ico</sup>